# 3-D Object Disappears When I Hit Save in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Why does this happen? Has anyone had this happen before? I have tried it numerous times to make sure I am not crazy and I can't find anyone who has had this problem before when I searched le internet.

This is what I am doing:

**Step 1:**

Put 3-D object on scene view.

**Step 2:**

Click Save

Edit:

Here is some more information:

Unity Version: 2019.2.21

What I did specifically:

I am following the directions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch1). One of the things that I did, that wasn't listed on the link is try to add a cube onto the scene view.

I did this by right clicking on "MixedRealityToolkit", choosing "3-D" object, and then selecting "cube".

I then hit save and my cube disappeared.

Comment: I guess the MRTK simply has some special implementation removing any object added below it. I just confirmed it and same happens when entering PlayMode without saving .. sounds like they wanted to make sure you don't add anything to it. Rather put your stuff either under the `MixedRealityPlaySpace` or anywhere else in your scene except under the `MixedRealityToolkit` object ;)

Comment: Ah, I am new to unity, a whole 3 days of experience :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MixedRealityToolkit is the MR dev toolkit itself, and providing the central configuration entry point for the entire framework.

We should not add any game object under the MixedRealityToolkit object. Therefore, the best practice is creating an empty object as a root game object, and then move all your scene contents as child to it.